# Why doesn´t my Blender in Linux detect a compatible GPU on the HIP tab on Cycles Render Devices section of the System setting?

Tags: graphics, amd-graphics, radeon, blender

## Notes:

- I dual boot my laptop with Windows 11 and Linux Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.
- My device is Lenovo Ideapad Slim 3 14ABA7 which uses AMD Ryzen™ 5 5625U Mobile Processors with AMD Radeon™ Graphics.
- I only get this problem in Linux.
- I installed Blender on Linux using the way that provided by the Blender official documentation.

## In Linux

When I opened my Blender setting and go to the System and selected the HIP tab on the Cycles Render Devices, it shows like this:
[The setting windows screenshot on Linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9TDd.png)

## In Windows

But, when I open the Setting then go to System and selected the HIP tab on the Cycles Render Devices, it shows like this:
[The same setting windows but in Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yNli.png)

What should I do so that my Blender in Linux can detect the GPU and utilise the HIP?

## What I have tried on my Linux:

1. Download the Radeon™ Software for Linux® version 22.40.5 for Ubuntu 22.04.2 from https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu-install/22.40.5/ubuntu/jammy/amdgpu-install_5.4.50405-1_all.deb
2. Installing it using the way that provided by the documentation (https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-prereq.html):
   a. Installing the Installer Package

```
$ cd ~/Downloads
# For Ubuntu:
$ sudo apt-get install ./amdgpu-install-VERSION.deb
$ sudo apt-get update
```

b. Open the manpage of amdgpu-install by invoke `amdgpu-install -h` and then `amdgpu-install --list-usecase`on my terminal window to learn how to utilise amdgpu-install to install the AMDGPU stack.
c. Then I decided to invoke this line in my terrminal Window: `amdgpu-install --usecase=graphics,opencl,hip --opencl=legacy --vulkan=amdvlk --accept-eula`.

When I was doing those steps, I expected that my system would be able to detect my GPU and so did the Blender. And thus the Blender could use the HIP ability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I have solved this problem several days ago

---

### What the problem was:

What I have tried on my Linux by installing Radeon™ Software for Linux® version 22.40.5 for Ubuntu 22.04.2 the way that the documentation provided was correct. The problem was I didn't know that after installing it, I should have added my [user_name] into the `video` and `render` groups by invoking the following commands:

`sudo usermod -a -G video [user]`

`sudo usermod -a -G render [user]`

### What I have done to solve:

But unfortunately, I had thoroughly uninstalled the Radeon™ Software for Linux® version 22.40.5 for Ubuntu 22.04.2. Therefore, I reinstalled it the way as I said in the question above. But on the step of invoking the command `amdgpu-install --usecase=graphics,opencl,hip --opencl=legacy --vulkan=amdvlk --accept-eula`, I invoked the default command `amdgpu-install -y` (which installed the `usecases: dkms,graphics,opencl,hip`) instead since I didn't really know what the `vulkan` was and what it was used for.

After that, I added my [user_name] into the `video` and `render` groups by invoking the following commands:

`sudo usermod -a -G video [user]`

`sudo usermod -a -G render [user]`

This is the screenshot of the HIP tab on the Cycles Render Devices in my Blender in Linux after doing that:
[image: The screenshot on Linux after I solved the problem]